# pip can't install tkinter in python 2.7

Tags: python, tkinter, pip

[So this is what is actually happening guys](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsGPT.jpg)

I would have changed my python version but I am not going to do that, because I'll have to write exams in python 2.7 and I don't wanna get confused. 
So have you got any ideas on fixing that guys?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Python comes with Tkinter... Try

```
>>> import Tkinter
```

in the python interpreter.

Edit: Proof (raw build of python 2.6)

```
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84297, Aug 24 2010, 18:13:38) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on
win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import Tkinter
>>> Tkinter
<module 'Tkinter' from 'C:\Python26\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.pyc'>
>>>
```

Comment: It says name 'tkinter' is not defined. I think that they added tkinter in python after python 3 version.

Comment: Check capitalisation.

Comment: Yeah it was the capitalisation, thank you brother. Somewhere I read that capitalisation was for the newer versions, it was wrong. Thank you again !

Answer (score 0):

Tkinter comes with python 2.7 and just check using 
import Tkinter

and then Tkinter

Capitalization works "T"